# Referrer header not included in stylesheet request inside iframe

Tags: iframe, referrer

I'm trying to load in an external font (using the font provider's hosted CSS) from inside a sandboxed iframe. The font provider seems to be authorizing whether the font can load or not based on the contents of the `Referrer` header. However, when the request is made from inside the iframe, that header is not present (according to Chrome's devtools). Setting `referrerpolicy="origin"` on the `<iframe>` element doesn't seem to change anything. Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Do I need to add a special attribute to my `<link>` tag, too? Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: any chance you ever found a solution to this?  I am seeing the same issue on my cordova iOS app using the WKWebView for iOS.  I added the `referrerpolicy="origin"` to the iFrame tag and it had no affect either.